# Is using 2 antivirus or malware software programs simultaneously helpful or useful?

Tags: networking, anti-virus

Is it good to install 2 antiviruses if they have different purposes?

For example, the 1st antivirus would:

1. Scan for Trojans
2. Scan for Worms
3. Scan for Viruses

And the other would:

4. Block Ads.
5. Have A Shredder

Answer (score 4):

1. If both antivirus scan your disk for virus/malware/whatnot, that's going to **slowdown your machine significantly** because there are **too many I/O ops per second**, and mostly non-linear. Apart from that, if both antivirus are scanning your system and detect a suspicious file, they'll fight each other - when A quarantines the file, B may detect it as threat and move it to quarantine as well, and this might keep going forever - or until A looks angry at B, or vice-versa.
2. With this in mind, many antivirus solutions allow you to **switch off some parts of their behaviour**, so you could keep the filesystem scanning turned on in the one antivirus, and disable it on the other.
3. Another concern is that some antivirus have their own firewalls, and most of these firewalls are built as kernel drivers (at least on Windows), so one might affect the other.

If a subsystem is present in both antivirus, I'd advise you to disable it in at least one. That way your system will assuredly run smoother.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jwyrich answer, but I think it should be expanded upon.

Programs with different "antivirus like" functions can - and arguably should both be run on the same machine, but not 2 programs with the same function.

There seems to be a distinction made between Antivirus software and Anti-Malware software - running something like malwarebytes in conjunction with an AV program is a good idea as they perform complimentary functions.

Running Norton Antivirus and AVG for example is not a great idea.